# Delphi error "E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to" 64 bit

Tags: delphi

I am trying to compile the Magenta packet capturing units to 64 bit.

https://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp

When I compile I get the dreaded Left side cannot be assigned to on the following line of code

```
LongWord(bp) := LongWord(bp) + BPF_WORDALIGN(caplen + hdrlen);
```

This is because the `LongWord` cast is different byte length in 64 right?  Can anyone help properly fix the line so it compiles happily in 32 and 64 bit versions? `bp` is declared as a pointer. `caplen` and `hdrlen` are declared as integers.

The `BPF_WORDALIGN` function is

```
function BPF_WORDALIGN(X:LongWord) : LongWord;
begin
     result := (((X)+(BPF_ALIGNMENT-1))and not(BPF_ALIGNMENT-1));
end;
```

Thanks for any help to get this working.

Here is the full procedure with the faulty line if that helps;

```
function pcap_read( p:PPcap;cnt:integer;CallBack:Tpcap_handler;User:pointer)
     : integer;
var cc   : Longword;//Counter ?
n    : integer;
bp,ep: pointer; //Begin and End Point ?
//bhp  : Pbpf_hdr;//pointer to BPF header struct - removed by Lars Peter
hdrlen,         //Length of Header
caplen: integer;//Length of captured
begin
  if NOT LoadPacketDll then
  begin
     p.errbuf := 'Cannot load packet.dll';
     result:=-1;
     exit;
  end;
  cc := p.cc;
  n  := 0;

  if p.cc = 0 then
    begin

   // *Capture the Packets*
     if PacketReceivePacket(p.adapter,p.packet,TRUE)=false then
     begin
       // ERROR!
       p.errbuf :='Read Error: PacketRecievePacket failed';
       result:=-1;
       exit;
     end;
     cc := p.packet.ulBytesReceived;

     bp := p.buffer;

    end else bp := p.bp;


// Loop through each packet.

ep := ptr(longword(bp)+cc); //move end pointer
while (longword(bp) < longword(ep) ) do
  begin
    caplen := Pbpf_hdr(bp).bh_caplen;
    hdrlen := Pbpf_hdr(bp).bh_hdrlen;

    // XXX A bpf_hdr matches apcap_pkthdr.

    callback(user,
    Ppcap_pkthdr(bp),
    ptr(longword(bp)+longword(HdrLen)));

    LongWord(bp) := LongWord(bp) + BPF_WORDALIGN(caplen + hdrlen);

    inc(n);
    if (n >= cnt)and(cnt>0) then
      begin
        p.bp := bp;
        p.cc := longword(ep)-longword(bp);
        result := n;
        exit;
      end;
      end;

   p.cc := 0;
   result:=n;
end;
```

Comment: We don't know what bp is. Probably a pointer. The cast should be `NativeUInt`. You should study the surrounding code to be sure. There are probably other errors that won't be found by the compiler. You are going to need to really understand this to solve it. Don't expect to get on top of this without doing some learning.

Comment: OK, I added the full function code if that helps?

Comment: Rather than have us do the work, have you considered gaining understanding? You ask for us to help you make the code compile, but that's really not a useful goal. You want the code to be correct. So many potential mistakes here with all this casting, and many can't be detected by the compiler.

Comment: @gammatester No, that does something else completely

Comment: LongWords need to be recast as FixedUInt right?  But even after that, I still get leftside error.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  That got it compiling.  Now it crashes elsewhere.  I am assuming this code is full of non 64 bit aware calls.

Comment: I never understood why Embarcadero introduced `Fixed(U)Int` when they already had `(U)Int32`. Both are inappropriate for this task, though. You need to use `Native(U)Int` instead when casting pointers. But personally, I wouldn't cast pointers to integers at all. Since `bp` and `ep` are pointers, consider using pointer arithmetic instead, eg: `ep := PByte(bp)+cc; ... callback(..., PByte(bp)+HdrLen); ... bp := PByte(bp) + BPF_WORDALIGN(caplen + hdrlen);` and so on

Comment: No. Not `FixedUInt`. It's `NativeUInt` you want, as per my first comment. And yes, as I said, there are sure to be lots of other errors. You'll need to do some learning. I know you don't want to. I know you want the code to be correct now. But that's not realistic. There are no shortcuts here.

Comment: There are probably a few more errors. You can be lucky that BPF_WORDALIGN(a + b) works, but it should very likely be BPF_WORD_ALIGN(a) + BPF_WORDALIGN(b).. But why not use the proper structure and bhp? This manual pointer math is never a good idea. Let the compiler calculate the alignment, by using the proper struct and a pointer to it. If the last part is open-ended, make it an empty record.

Comment: @Rudy Think about it Rudy. The offsets involved are only known at runtime. Compiler can't do it.

Comment: Note that when you translate such a package, originally written for Win32, to Win64, you'll probably have to convert some types to 64 bit but others must remain 32 bit. You'll have to understand which is which. This means you can't blindly cast everything to Navite(U)Int. You will really have to understand what you are doing. Or use a better library, which can handle 32 and 64 bit equally well.

Comment: @David: Ah, yes, I guess you are right. I see that the second offset is probably the offset into an array. But not the first, that seems to be the header length.